# How to make a div top center?

Tags: html, css

I'm now doing it this way,which is not centered:

```
$div = $('<div style="background-color:yellow;position:absolute;top:0;"><b>Loading...</b></div>').appendTo('body');
```

Comment: I think margin-top:-5%; would fix it i think so ... Just give try

Answer (score 3):

For auto margins to work you also need to define a width for the div as well, else it just takes up the whole screen width and you'll see no difference.

However, in this instance all you need is to add `text-align: center;` to your original CSS as far as I can see?

Comment: Do you have firebug by your hand?why not run it to see whether it works?

Comment: ...oh, but if you want it absolute positioned you'll need left:0; and right:0; too.

Comment: In this context they make your div full screen width, and text-align:center will put your text in the middle of the div. Full CSS you need would be:

background-color:yellow;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;text-align:center;

Answer (score 1):

Give it

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: You'll need to remove position: absolute too

Comment: setting left/right margins to auto doesn't work for IE, does it?  At least not <=IE7

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <div style="text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 50%; background: yellow">
    Your text here
  </div>
</div>
```